# StrSubstitutor replacement with JRE libraries

Tags: string, text, java

At the moment I am using `org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrSubstitutor` for doing:

```
Map m = ...
substitutor = new StrSubstitutor(m);

result = substitutor.replace(input);
```

Given the fact I want to remove `commons-lang` dependency from my project what would be a working and minimalistic implementation of `StrSubstitutor` using standard JRE libraries?

**Note**:

`StrSubstitutor` works like this:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
map.put("target", "lazy dog");
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(map);
String resolvedString = sub.replace("The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.");
```

yielding resolvedString = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

Comment: libraries simplify your code, why do you want to remove dependency?

Comment: It seems that a simple loop over the entrySet, and calling `inputString.replace("${" + key + "}", value);` would do the trick (possibly not in the most efficient way). Or take the code you need from commons-lang...

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: "a working and minimalistic implementation" - Parse your string for the relevant delimiters and replace them in the returned value. - Can you be more specific?

Comment: PeterLawrey: assylians just provided one valid answer. hoaz: dependencies are problematic since they are transitive and they may clash with other libraries dependencies. hanno-binder: it looks like you understood what I am trying to do (without the dependency).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<strike>If performance is not a priority,</strike> you can use the [`appendReplacement` method of the `Matcher` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public class StrSubstitutor {
    private Map<String, String> map;
    private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.+?)\\}");

    public StrSubstitutor(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public String replace(String str) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (m.find()) {
            String var = m.group(1);
            String replacement = map.get(var);
            m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

A more performant but uglier version, just for fun :)

```
    public String replace(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < strArray.length - 1) {
            if (strArray[i] == '$' && strArray[i + 1] == '{') {
                i = i + 2;
                int begin = i;
                while (strArray[i] != '}') ++i;
                sb.append(map.get(str.substring(begin, i++)));
            } else {
                sb.append(strArray[i]);
                ++i;
            }
        }
        if (i < strArray.length) sb.append(strArray[i]);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

It's about 2x as fast as the regex version and 3x faster than the apache commons version as per my tests. So the normal regex stuff is actually more optimized than the apache version. Usually not worth it of course. Just for fun though, let me know if you can make it more optimized.

**Edit**: As @kmek points out, there is a caveat. Apache version will resolve transitively. e.g, If `${animal}` maps to `${dog}` and `dog` maps to `Golden Retriever`, apache version will map `${animal}` to Golden Retriever. As I said, you should use libraries as far as possible. The above solution is only to be used if you have a special constraint which does not allow you to use a library.

Comment: at fist sight it doesn't look bad at all. why do you think this shouldn't be optimal for performances? I find it, pretty neat!

Comment: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.+?)\\}");` can be moved and initialized as field; can't it?

Comment: Well, to get uber performance, you could write it without using regexes at all - you can scan it char by char, use buffers etc. Yes, you can make the `Pattern` static. I'll make that change..

Comment: An easy optimization is to replace the StringBuffer with StringBuilder (should be around 20-30% faster). I wanted to wait for additional suggestions, but your answer is just to excellent to wait :)

Comment: I don't believe this solution accounts for tags being replaced by more tags, for example
`map.put("dog", "Golden Retriever"); map.put("animal", "${dog}");`

Apache's version does the double replacement meaning 
`substitutor.replace("the animal is ${animal}")`
yields
`the animal is Golden Retriever`
vs the solution provided returns
`the animal is ${dog}`

Comment: @kmek This is true. However, I don't think that's what the OP wanted. I'll update the answer with this caveat though.

Answer (score 1):

there's nothing like this that i know of in the JRE, but writing one is simple enough.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("${([a-zA-Z]+)}";
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
int lastEnd = -1;
while (m.find(lastEnd+1)) {
   int startIndex = m.start();
   String varName = m.group(1);
   //lookup value in map and substitute
   inputString = inputString.substring(0,m.start())+replacement+inputString.substring(m.end());
   lastEnt = m.start() + replacement.size();
}
```

this is of course horribly inefficient and you should probably write the result into a StringBuilder instead of replacing inputString all the time

Comment: In Java, if you're using a regex pattern, you can use the `replaceAll` method of String instead.

Comment: 1st of all using Pattern yourself is slightly more efficient since you dont need to constantly compile new expressions for each variable. 2nd if i want to use a StringBuilder to write the output to for efficiency i need to scan the string in order