# Java generating Strings with placeholders

Tags: java, string, string-interpolation

I'm looking for something to achieve the following:

```java
String s = "hello {}!";
s = generate(s, new Object[]{ "world" });
assertEquals(s, "hello world!"); // should be true
```

I could write it myself, but It seems to me that I saw a library once which did this, probably it was the slf4j logger, but I don't want to write log messages. I just want to generate strings.

Do you know about a library which does this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format

Comment: The slf4J uses `org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter`
The code looks like this:
   `String str = "Hello this is {} string {}";
    MessageFormatter.format(str, new String[]{"hello", "world", "blah"}).getMessage();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String replacement in java, similar to a velocity template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655424/string-replacement-in-java-similar-to-a-velocity-template)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

See [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method.

```
String s = "hello %s!";
s = String.format(s, "world");
assertEquals(s, "hello world!"); // should be true
```

Comment: how to replace two `String`s in the same `format()` ? example `String.format("%s %s!", ["hello", "world"]);` is this possible?

Comment: @Carlos.V use `String.format("Hello %s welcome to %s!", "Carlos. V", "JAVA");` will print `Hello Carlos. V welcome to JAVA!` and you can use as many %s as you can. :)

Answer (score 45):

`StrSubstitutor` from Apache Commons Lang may be used for string formatting with named placeholders:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html :

> Substitutes variables within a string by values.
>
> This class takes a piece of text and substitutes all the variables
> within it. The default definition of a variable is ${variableName}.
> The prefix and suffix can be changed via constructors and set methods.
>
> Variable values are typically resolved from a map, but could also be
> resolved from system properties, or by supplying a custom variable
> resolver.

Example:

```
String template = "Hi ${name}! Your number is ${number}";

Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put("name", "John");
data.put("number", "1");

String formattedString = StrSubstitutor.replace(template, data);
```

Comment: The StrSubstitutor is deprecated, see [this SO post for a work around.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044715/strsubstitutor-replacement-with-jre-libraries)

Comment: The `org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor` from `org.apache.commons:commons-text:x.y` has taken it's place. Simply drop that one in and you're good to go without deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 42):

This can be done in a single line without the use of library. Please check `java.text.MessageFormat` class.

Example

```
String stringWithPlaceHolder = "test String with placeholders {0} {1} {2} {3}";
String formattedStrin = java.text.MessageFormat.format(stringWithPlaceHolder, "place-holder-1", "place-holder-2", "place-holder-3", "place-holder-4");
```

Output will be

```
test String with placeholders place-holder-1 place-holder-2 place-holder-3 place-holder-4
```

Comment: This is the best solution when adding localization as the place holder order changes for different languages .

Answer (score 14):

If you can change the format of your placeholder, you could use `String.format()`. If not, you could also replace it as pre-processing.

```
String.format("hello %s!", "world");
```

More information in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format).

Answer (score 9):

There are two solutions:

- [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html);
- [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

`Formatter` is more recent even though it takes over `printf()` which is 40 years old...

Your placeholder as you currently define it is one `MessageFormat` can use, but why use an antique technique? ;) Use `Formatter`.

There is all the more reason to use `Formatter` that you don't need to escape single quotes! `MessageFormat` requires you to do so. Also, `Formatter` has a shortcut via `String.format()` to generate strings, and `PrintWriter`s have `.printf()` (that includes `System.out` and `System.err` which are both `PrintWriter`s by default)

Comment: I remember reading/testing that MessageFormat was pretty slow.

Comment: @assylias meh, I don't know, my message bundle API proposes both since I have `ResourceBundle` compatibility... But I personally always use `Formatter`.

Comment: I am not sure to be honest - and in most situations it won't make a difference anyway.

Comment: `MessageFormat` does have a few advantages over `Formatter` though, particularly the possibility to embed [`ChoiceFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html) expressions.

Comment: @gustafc not a problem, `Formatter` has [`Formattable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formattable.html), which is even more powerful ;)

Comment: @fge I wouldn't say that's a clearly better option in all circumstances, the canonical example being format strings like `Found {0,choice,0#nothing|1#one thing|{0} things}`

Answer (score 7):

You won't need a library; if you are using a recent version of Java, have a look at `String.format`:

```
String.format("Hello %s!", "world");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can tolerate a different kind of placeholder (i.e. `%s` in place of `{}`) you can use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method for that:

```
String s = "hello %s!";
s = String.format(s, "world" );
assertEquals(s, "hello world!"); // true
```

Answer (score 4):

Justas answer is outdated so I'm posting up to date answer with apache text commons.

`StringSubstitutor` from Apache Commons Text may be used for string formatting with named placeholders:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

> This class takes a piece of text and substitutes all the variables
> within it. The default definition of a variable is ${variableName}.
> The prefix and suffix can be changed via constructors and set methods.
> Variable values are typically resolved from a map, but could also be
> resolved from system properties, or by supplying a custom variable
> resolver.

Example:

```
// Build map
Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
String templateString = "The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.";

// Build StringSubstitutor
StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap);

// Replace
String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use some string to different placeholders, you could use pointers like this:

```
String.format("%1$s %2$s %1$s", "startAndEndText", "middleText");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are user spring you can like this:

```
String template = "hello #{#param}";
EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setVariable("param", "world");
String value = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(template, new TemplateParserContext()).getValue(context, String.class);
System.out.println(value);
```

out put:

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is going to have string templates (from version **21**, as a preview feature).

See [the string templates proposal (JEP 430) here](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430).

It will be something along the lines of this:

```java
String name = "World";
String info = STR."Hello \{name}!";
System.out.println(info); // Hello World!
```

---

P.S. [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) is 100% interoperable with Java. It supports cleaner string templates out of the box:

```kotlin
val name = "World"
val info = "Hello $name!"
println(info) // Hello World!
```

Combined with [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html), you can achieve the same thing the Java template processors (e.g. `STR`) will do.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4290127/himanshu-chaudhary works quite well:

```
String str = "Hello this is {} string {}";     
str = MessageFormatter.format(str, "hello", "world").getMessage();
```

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0-beta4</version>
</dependency>
```