# How to replace named parameter in a string

Tags: java, string, formatting

I am working on a project built on `Java`.
I have a use case where I have multiple templates of `strings` that need to be formatted by replacing keywords with their values.

Since the position of parameter and name of the parameter is not always known and will change over time I want to write a function that takes a string and replace keywords (named parameter) with their values using the map.

For e.g.

```
Hi my name is %name
```

And if I have map = {"name":"user1"}

Then my function should replace the name with user1.

I tried to find if there is already an existing method or library in java but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Can you share your code with us

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java generating Strings with placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364632/java-generating-strings-with-placeholders)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like that (using a map and replacing all occurrences of keys starting with %):

```
Map<String, String> map= new HashMap();
map.put("name1", "user1");
map.put("name2", "user2");

String str = "Hi my name is %name1. Hi my name is %name2 and %name1";

String result = map.keySet()
                   .stream()
                   .reduce(str, (s, e) -> s.replaceAll("%"+e+"\\b", map.get(e)));
    
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need that:

```
String name = "Chack";//you will get its field from your map = {"name":"user1"}
String.format("Hi my name is %s", name);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use simply String.format:

```
String name = "Example"
String.format("Hi my name is %s", name);
```

Or message format:

```
String exampleTemplate = "Hi my name is {0}";
String name = "Example Name"
String message = MessageFormat.format(exampleTemplate, name);
```